# Combining Normally distributed Random Variables

Tags: normal-distribution

This question involves combining random variables from Normal distributions:

[image]

Because the box contains 12 of these components I multiplied the individual component mean and variance by 12, so I got: X~N(560.4, 21.6).

However, the answer just divides the variance by 12:

[image]

I don't understand this?

Comment: This is because sampling distribution of the mean when sample size is $n$ for a $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ population is $N(\mu,\sigma^2/n)$.

Comment: @Shahab Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $X_1, X_2, \ldots$ are the weights of the individual components, you computed the variance of

$$ X_1 + X_2 + X_3 + X_4 + X_5 + X_6 + X_7 + X_8 + X_9 + X_{10} + X_{11} + X_{12}. $$

But that's the *total* weight of the entire box of components.
You were asked to find the distribution of the *mean* weight of the components, which is

$$ \frac{1}{12}(X_1 + X_2 + X_3 + X_4 + X_5 + X_6 + X_7 + X_8 + X_9 + X_{10} + X_{11} + X_{12}). $$

Now remember that if $k$ is a constant real number,
the variance of $k X$ is $k^2$ times the variance of $X.$

Comment: Thanks. Yes. Doh